Expo SDK Version Mismatch
I started my expo project with expo SDK 50, but then i tried to upgrade  to expo 51. I used a command that automatically updates all the dependencies in a project ( i dont remember which one), then npm automatically deleted the entire node_modules folder. but after that, when npm was about to reinstall node_modeuls, my pc suddenly turned off due to electricity issues. and when i turned it on again, i had to use a command to reinstall the node modules (perhaps npm install). then it reinstalled the modules as per mentioned in package.json or something i am not sure. now, expo SDK 51 is installed in my project, still when I try to open this in expo go app it says that I have SDK 50 in my project. I suspect that even though the modules were installed, they were not changed in certain files, coz I just noticed that my package.json says that I am using expo version 50 in my project (i changed to 51 now). what I can do?
I tried to change Expo Version Number in both package.json and package-lock.json. Still having the same issue. Now I also suspect that the versions of other packages might be mismatched too.
